# How to get a different handle using clone() on DB handle created by connect_cache?

Tags: perl, fork, clone, dbi

The Honorable Jury!

I have found an issue with Perl DBI which may be either a bug or a feature. I bet the first. :)

I found that [$dbh->clone()](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#clone) returns the same `$dbh` if created by [DBI->connect_cached()](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect_cached).

Here is the example code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI 1.614;

my %attr = (PrintError => 1);
my @conn = ('DBI:Oracle:MYSERVER', 'Solaris', '****', \%attr);

print "#### Simple connect ############################################\n";

{
my $dbh1 = DBI->connect(@conn); print $dbh1,"\n";
my $dbh2 = DBI->connect(@conn); print $dbh2,"\n";
my $dbh3 = $dbh1->clone(\%attr); print $dbh3,"\n";
}

print "#### Cached connect ############################################\n";

{
my $dbh1 = DBI->connect_cached(@conn); print $dbh1,"\n";
my $dbh2 = DBI->connect_cached(@conn); print $dbh2,"\n";
my $dbh3 = $dbh1->clone(\%attr); print $dbh3,"\n";
}

print "#### Cached connect with private ###############################\n";

{
$attr{private_data} = 1;
my $dbh1 = DBI->connect_cached(@conn); print $dbh1,"\n";
$attr{private_data} = 2;
my $dbh2 = DBI->connect_cached(@conn); print $dbh2,"\n";
$attr{private_data} = 3;
my $dbh3 = $dbh1->clone(\%attr); print $dbh3,"\n";
}

print "#### END #######################################################\n";
```

And the output is:

```
#### Simple connect ############################################
DBI::db=HASH(0x27ec838)
DBI::db=HASH(0x27ed138)
DBI::db=HASH(0x2b53638)
#### Cached connect ############################################
DBI::db=HASH(0x28863d8)
DBI::db=HASH(0x28863d8)
DBI::db=HASH(0x28863d8)
#### Cached connect with private ###############################
DBI::db=HASH(0x27ec880)
DBI::db=HASH(0x2b53e48)
DBI::db=HASH(0x27ec880)
#### END #######################################################
```

- Simple `connect` works as I expected. New connect to the same service/user returns different `$dbh` and the clone() alike.
- Cached connect also works as expected. The same `$dbh` returned in all 3 cases.
- Finally I applied a private_* attribute as stated in the documentation in [connect_cached](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect_cached). It works only for the `connect_cached` calls, but providing the unique attribute to `clone` does not give a new DBI handle as I expected based on the [clone](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#clone)'s description. But maybe my expectation is false.

The real problem is that I would like to implement a [fork()](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) proof solution. I set the [AutoInactiveDestroy](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#AutoInactiveDestroy) for all newly created `$dbh`s and everything is working fine, except I cannot get a unique handle for an existing `$dbh` created by [connect_cached](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect_cached) in the parent process contrary I set the `private_pid` attribute equal to the pid of the current process. I checked the `DBI.pm` source and [clone](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#clone) calls the internal `dbi_connect_closure` of the original `$dbh` and this closure calls `connect` or `connect_cached` methods based on the original `$dbh`'s connect method. So, I think it should consider the unique `private_*` attribute and return a new `$dbh`.

As a workaround I do a `connect_cashed` each time instead of the `clone` call.

Please share any information which may help to solve or workaround the issue.

Versions:

```
Perl : v5.26.2
DBI  : 1.641
Linux: 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64
```

Thanks in advance! Truey

Comment: Have you tried https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector?

Comment: @Pradeep Thanks for the hint! The $dbh is created by some other module, so I can set some attributes, but connect is not done my code.What is more I cannot install new Perl modules as the environment is not maintained by me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no DBI expert. I tried to lookup the DBI `clone()` code, but that rapidly goes into C/XS details that are a bit over my head :-)

One suggestion I can make is to pay attention to your `%attr` hash. You are passing a reference to the same `%attr` to each `connect_cache()` and `clone()` call. Meaning, by the time you get to your `$dbh3` handle, all handles will reference the same attributes with `private_data = 3`.

I assume `clone()` will check if the attributes reference is the same (as in, points to the same `%attr` hash). If it is, you will be given the same handle by `clone()`.

Try this change:

```
...
print "#### Cached connect with private ###############################\n";

{
$attr{private_data} = 1;
my $dbh1 = DBI->connect_cached(@conn); print $dbh1,"\n";
$attr{private_data} = 2;
my $dbh2 = DBI->connect_cached(@conn); print $dbh2,"\n";
my %dbh3_attr = ( PrintError => 1, private_data => 3 );
my $dbh3 = $dbh1->clone(\%dbh3_attr); print $dbh3,"\n";
}

print "#### END #######################################################\n";
```

I believe you will get a different result than what you reported above.